# Scala XML fetch a value based on tag name

Tags: xml, scala

Is it possible to get the value of a tag based on the tags name? For example., in the following xml,

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b>one</b>
    <c>two</c>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>two</b>
    <c>one</c>
  </a>
</root>
```

And when I do the following:

```
val aNodes = root \\ "a"
aNodes.map(aNode => {
  aNode. ??? // How to I get the value of b and c by using its tag name?
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text content of the children elements `b` and `c` by navigating to them using the `\` path projection function and calling the `NodeSeq.text` method on the results:

```
(xml \\ "a") map (e => ((e \ "b") text, (e \ "c") text)) // List((one,two), (two,one))
```

This returns a `Tuple2` containing the values for `b` and `c` for all `a` elements.